# Delete Post Authorize Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, api, authorization, policy

I want delete a post with authorization but failed with error "message": false,
"errors": "This action is unauthorized."

destroy controller

```
public function destroy($id, Post $post)
{
    try {
        $this->authorize('delete', $post);
        $posts = Post::find($id);
        $posts->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Success'
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => false,
            'errors' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }

}
```

policy

```
public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id == $post->user_id;
}
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vupLP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the user is good connected. Which api do you used.? If sanctum or passport, you need to specified in your Header Request on Postman, attribute `Authorization` with the value `Bearer your_token`
That will create a request like you where connected as the user who owns the token.
You can also check the value by debbuging like this, and look at the response.

```
var_dump($post->user_id);
var_dump($user);
die();
```

Comment: NULL 
what should i add?

because I already use token

Comment: i use sanctum for api

Comment: follow all the step here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum